# Can't connect to App Store Mojave 10.14.2 on VMWare

Tags: app-store, macos-mojave, vmware-workstation

Installed Mojave 10.14.2 on VMWare on Windows 10 x64. Although Safari works and I can surf the Web and sign in to iTunes too, App Store says: **Cannot connect to App Store**. And even can't sign in to App Store.
I need to update Mojave to 10.14.4

Tested these solutions, but no success yet!

1- Changed "When using this certificate" from Use System Defaults to "Never Trust" in System Roots of KeyChain Access.

2- Added DNS addresses: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to the DNS Server in *Network*.

3- Searched for **/var/db/crls/** but don't have files: "cricache.db" or "ocspcache.db" there!

4- In Terminal, in "/library/secturity", wrote: **sudo ditto -ck "Trust Settings" TrustSettingsBackup.zip** and then hit password. The result was: "ditto: no files for PKZip archive". Then in "/Library/Security/Trust Settings" wrote: **sudo rm *.plist**, result: rm: *.plist: No such file or directory.*

There is no red/yellow warning mark in the network settings, either:

[image]

How to solve the issue and then update Mac to 10.14.4, please?

Comment: I downloaded MacOS X Mojave 10.14.4 and could update Mac. But once again, I can't connect my App Store to the Internet even right now! Why is Mojave this way? :(